# How to remove .zip file in c on windows? (error: Directory not empty)

Tags: c, winapi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include "win32-dirent.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <direct.h>

#define MAXFILEPATH 1024

bool IsDirectory(char* path)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA w32fd;
    HANDLE hFindFile;

    hFindFile = FindFirstFile((PTCHAR)path, &w32fd);

    if(hFindFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return w32fd.dwFileAttributes & (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY); 
}

int RD(const char* folderName)
{
        DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *ent;

        dir = opendir(folderName);
        if(dir != NULL)
        {
                while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
                {
                        if(strcmp(ent->d_name , ".") == 0 ||
                                strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0)
                        {
                                continue;
                        }

                        char fileName[MAXFILEPATH];
                        sprintf(fileName,"%s%c%s", folderName, '\\', ent->d_name);                        
                        if(IsDirectory(fileName))
                        {
                            RD(fileName);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            unlink(fileName);
                        }
                }

                closedir(dir);

                //chmod(folderName, S_IWRITE | S_IREAD);
                if(_rmdir(folderName) != 0)perror(folderName);              

        }
        else
        {
                printf("%s <%s>\n","Could Not Open Directory.", folderName);
                return -1;
        }

        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        if(argc < 2)
        {
                printf("usage: ./a.out <target folder name>\n");
        return 1;
        }

        //RD(argv[1]);
        //_mkdir("12");
        //_mkdir("12\\34");
        //_rmdir("12\\34");
        //_rmdir("12");
        char buf[0xff];
        sprintf(buf, "unzip -x -q -d 1234 1234.zip");
        system(buf);

        RD("1234");

        //unlink("D:\\dev\\c\\project\\removeFolder\\Debug\\1234\\56\\5.txt");
        //unlink("D:\\dev\\c\\project\\removeFolder\\Debug\\1234\\56\\6.txt");
        //unlink("D:\\dev\\c\\project\\removeFolder\\Debug\\1234\\1_23.zip");
        //unlink("D:\\dev\\c\\project\\removeFolder\\Debug\\1234\\4.txt");
        //_rmdir("D:\\dev\\c\\project\\removeFolder\\Debug\\1234\\56");
        //_rmdir("D:\\dev\\c\\project\\removeFolder\\Debug\\1234");

        return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
--------------------------
Archive:  1234.zip
  inflating: 1234/4.txt
  inflating: 1234/56/5.txt
  inflating: 1234/56/6.txt
  inflating: 1234/1_23.zip
--------------------------
```

Comment: You need to post a *question*.  Describe your problem as concisely and clearly as possible, using short code samples to clarify your question where appropriate - you will get a far better response this way (people dislike having to understand lengthy code samples)

Comment: Please add some more detail on the question description... It will help others to give you correct answer...

Comment: Actually, I'm going to vote to reopen. While not the best-formed question in the galaxy, it has both the code _and_ the error being caused by that code. I think we can extrapolate that to a simple "How do I get past that error?" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks feasible at first glance, you recursively clean up directories before attempting to remove them.

One thing comes immediately to mind, the possibility that you have the zip file opened up in another application, hence possibly locked.

You generally won't get "directory not empty" errors unless, well, the directory isn't empty.

For a start, change the line:

```
if(_rmdir(folderName) != 0)perror(folderName);
```

to:

```
if(_rmdir(folderName) != 0) {
    char buf[1000];
    sprintf(buf,"dir \"%s\"",foldername);
    system(buf);
    perror(folderName);
}
```

and that should hopefully tell you what directory you're in and what the offending files are.